# jQuery contextMenu.js Как программно кликнуть по item созданного меню

Tags: jquery

jQuery contextMenu.js  Как  программно кликнуть по item созданного меню

Answer (score 1):

Программно кликнуть по любому элементу из jQuery можно так:

```
$(".test").trigger("click");
```